# I'm trying to use the c# file handle, but it's not available

Tags: c#

c# File handler error.I can't find it.

use SafeFileHandle filehandle -> error
I tried to copy it, but it didn't work out well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("검색할 경로를 입력하세요.");
            string result1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("파일 확장자를 입력하세요.");
            string result2 = Console.ReadLine();          
            Filehandle file1 = new Filehandle();
            file1.FileCheck(result1,result2);
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give more context about what you are trying to achieve? I get the feeling what you are looking for is `File` or `FileInfo`, not `Filehandle`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package in your project before you can use it.

```bash
dotnet add package Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles
```